# Azure data factory -

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create a pipeline where I am using SQL query as well as a spreadsheet and copy data to a blob

I have a query which extracts a certain number of columns in DB

I have a csv which has 3 columns

I have to join sql and csv using a common column and generate a csv file output

Note: I can only tweak in ADF. Cannot change anything on DB side.

Can ADF do this magic?

Comment: You could do this with a Data Flow activity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **@Joel Cochran**, you can do it with data flows in ADF.
You can use the `Join` transformation in data flows to get the result csv.

Please follow the demonstration below:

- Create two source datasets, one for the csv dataset and one for the Database table.
- **My source csv:**
  [image]
- **My Database table**(used SQL here):
  [image]
- In the database table source, you can give your query to select the required columns like below.
  [image]
- Now, use **join** transformation by clicking on the `+` icon on any source and give the **left and right streams**. As you want to join by common column, use the **inner join**. Give the **common column name** from the csv and database. Here, `csv_Id` and `id` are common in my case.
  [image]
- Here I have used select transformation to avoid the extra column of common column. Now, give the result csv dataset to the sink and use **output to single file** in the sink.
  [image]
- **My csv in the blob:**
  [image]

Comment: Appreciate your response. Thanks

Comment: Can I use data flow as source to copy activity?

Comment: Copy activity requires a dataset to be its source otherwise it won't execute. So, you can use the result dataset from the dataflow using wild card path in copy activity. For example, if data flow generates a csv file to a container, then in wildcard path of copy activity, give *.csv which detects our dataset and we can use it as source dataset.

Comment: @Indrajit, I have used Dataset option and given the Dataset. If you did the same, it should give you the options in sink settings. Close and reopen the ADF, then it may work. If still faces the same problem, contact MS support team to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks if you get chance can you share screenshot of that? (sink tab).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hBd7eG5.png